# Apache Storm nimbus start fails when run using python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, apache-storm

I am trying to install and run apache storm(version 1.0.2) on amazon linux instance.There is no problem in starting storm nimbus when I am root user. In other words, if is use the following commands

```
sudo su -

python /opt/apache-storm-1.0.2/bin/storm.py nimbus
```

it is working fine.
However if am an ec2-user and tries to execute the command as

```
sudo python /opt/apache-storm-1.0.2/bin/storm.py nimbus
```

it is giving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./storm.py", line 769, in <module>
    main()
  File "./storm.py", line 766, in main
    (COMMANDS.get(COMMAND, unknown_command))(*ARGS)
  File "./storm.py", line 529, in nimbus
    jvmopts = parse_args(confvalue("nimbus.childopts", cppaths)) + [
  File "./storm.py", line 145, in confvalue
    p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to run the command without switching as root user

Comment: the error you got looks like a path or permissions issue. typically Apache needs to be started as root because it binds to port 80  which can only be done by a root process.

Comment: Please check "sudo which python" to check python is available with sudo environment. I guess there're somewhat different for applying environments like .bashrc, .bash_profile, and so on.